# Oracle sql using row_num() query with group by

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I need to have a unique number field in my view so i tried to use the `row_num()` but i keep getting `"window error"`
 this is the syntax im using for creating the view:

```
create or replace view DASHBOARD_P_PEILUT_NIDRESHET 
as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by d.mahoz_name) rownum1  ,
           d.MAHOZ_NAME,d.PEILUT_NIDRESHET,g.shape ,COUNT(objectid) cnt_obj 
    from dashboard_mehoz_spatial_join d,sde_user.GiS_MEHOZ g
    where d.mahoz_name=g.mahoz_name
    group by ROW_NUMBER() , d.MAHOZ_NAME, d.PEILUT_NIDRESHET, g.shape 
);
```

and this is the error:

```
Error starting at line : 4 in command -
create or replace view DASHBOARD_P_PEILUT_NIDRESHET as (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by d.mahoz_name) rownum1  ,d.MAHOZ_NAME,d.PEILUT_NIDRESHET,g.shape ,COUNT(objectid) cnt_obj 
from dashboard_mehoz_spatial_join d,sde_user.GiS_MEHOZ g
where d.mahoz_name=g.mahoz_name
group by ROW_NUMBER() , d.MAHOZ_NAME, d.PEILUT_NIDRESHET, g.shape )
Error at Command Line : 7 Column : 10
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function
30484. 00000 -  "missing window specification for this function"
*Cause:    All window functions should be followed by window specification,
           like <function>(<argument list>) OVER (<window specification>)
*Action:
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't `group by` an analytic function.  But it is not necessary anyway.  Try this:

```
create or replace view DASHBOARD_P_PEILUT_NIDRESHET as
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by d.mahoz_name) as rownum1 ,
           d.MAHOZ_NAME, d.PEILUT_NIDRESHET, g.shape, COUNT(objectid) cnt_obj 
    from dashboard_mehoz_spatial_join d join
         sde_user.GiS_MEHOZ g
         on d.mahoz_name = g.mahoz_name
    group by d.MAHOZ_NAME, d.PEILUT_NIDRESHET, g.shape ;
```